# 広告（nend）を埋め込むと、背景画像が全画面表示できなくなってしまう

Tags: monaca, 画像, nend

「Monaca Docs
　ドキュメントTOP » サンプル＆Tips » 開発Tips » nend ( 日本のアドネットワーク )
　3.Monacaアプリへの広告コードの埋め込み」にそって
　広告コードの埋め込みを行ったとき、
　背景画像がbackground-size: cover;を無視し

```
<style>
      body {
        background-image: url("images/index_bg.png");
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
```

全画面表示より大きくなってしまいます。

↓埋め込み前後のスクリーンです。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
　背景は全画面表示を維持したまま
　広告掲載することは可能でしょうか？
　
　尚、埋め込んだコードは以下の通りです（Monacaアプリへの広告コードの埋め込みより転載）

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<script src="components/loader.js"></script>
<script>

var nend_params;

//iOS/Androidアプリそれぞれに共通のコードとする場合は下記のように処理を切り分けます。
if( monaca.isIOS ){
nend_params =     {"media":xxxx,"site":xxxxx,"spot":xxxxx,"type":x,"oriented":x}; // iOS
}
if( monaca.isAndroid ){
nend_params = {"media":xxxx,"site":xxxxx,"spot":xxxxx,"type":x,"oriented":x}; // Android
}
</script>
</head>
```